# method to take an element out from jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $('li').add('<p id="new">new paragraph</p>')
 .css('background-color', 'red');
```

Although the new paragraph has been created and its background color changed, it still does not appear on the page.What or which method/procedure i be able to place it on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do it wrong. If you want to append new paragraph to `<li>` element then use:

```
$('<p id="new">new paragraph</p>').css('background-color', 'red').appendTo('li');
```

Comment: @Maizere In this case you create new paragraph, set background colour to it and append it to `<li>`.

Comment: I belive the OP wants the li background to be red, not the paragraph.

Comment: @epascarello I believe not: *Although the new paragraph has been created and **its** background color changed...*

Answer (score 1):

Use `append` instead of `add`

```
$('li').append('<p id="new">new paragraph</p>')
 .css('background-color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this was the intended operation:

```
$('li').append('<p id="new">new paragraph</p>').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: Note: this changes the background-color of the whole `li` element, not just of the newly created paragraph. It is not clear what exactly is desired for the background-color.

Comment: @AlexShesterov you're right. I ignored that for the purposes of this particular question. The OP seemed to care more about getting the paragraph inserted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is `add()` does not add the element to another element. It adds the element to the jQuery collection. So you are adding the `<p>` element to the end of list of li elements. eg ~ `[li,li,li,p]`

From the jQuery docs for [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

> ### .add()
>
> ```
> .add( selector )Returns: jQuery
> ```
>
> Description: Add elements to the set of matched elements.

What you want is [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

> ### `.append()`
>
> ```
> .append( content [, content ] )Returns: jQuery
> ```
>
> Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of
>   each element in the set of matched elements.

So your code would work with just

```
$('li').append('<p id="new">new paragraph</p>').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Running Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ScpY/)